How to correctly simulate `atomicAdd` on `u64` by using two `u32` buffers?
I'm trying to do atomic operations on u64. But since it's not supported, the number is stored in TWO u32 buffers
The issue is that I'm not sure how to do atomicAdd correctly to simulate the effect it would have had on u64. All while avoiding memory modification by other threads between loading and storing the values.
my current idea is this:

fn tou64(value: u32) -> vec2u {
        return vec2u(u32(value / BASE), value % BASE);
}

fn add(a: vec2u, b: vec2u) -> vec2u {
    let x = a.x + b.x + u32((a.y + b.y) / BASE);
    let y = (a.y + b.y) % BASE;
    return vec2u(x, y);
}

fn main() {
// .....

// convert the value from u32 to 2-buffer representation of u64
let b: vec2u = tou64(value);
// fetch the old value from the 2 buffers
var a = vec2u(0); 
a.x = atomicLoad(&buffer[index]);
a.y = atomicLoad(&buffer[index+1]);
// add the value to the buffer value
let result = add(a, b);
// store back the buffer results 
atomicStore(&buffer[index], result.x);
atomicStore(&buffer[index+1], result.y);
}

This works only when no other thread modifies the buffer at the same index. But it's a very weak implementation otherwise. Thread 1 could change the value of buffer[index+1] while thread 2 just read the old buffer[index] value and the new buffer[index+1] value
Edit: in CUDA's guide, it's noted that:

Note that any atomic operation can be implemented based on atomicCAS() (Compare And Swap)

and this example of AtomicAdd on double is provided
#if __CUDA_ARCH__ < 600
__device__ double atomicAdd(double* address, double val)
{
    unsigned long long int* address_as_ull =
                              (unsigned long long int*)address;
    unsigned long long int old = *address_as_ull, assumed;

    do {
        assumed = old;
        old = atomicCAS(address_as_ull, assumed,
                        __double_as_longlong(val +
                               __longlong_as_double(assumed)));

    // Note: uses integer comparison to avoid hang in case of NaN (since NaN != NaN)
    } while (assumed != old);

    return __longlong_as_double(old);
}
#endif

can this be applied to webgpu as well using atomicExchange? this answer shows how to do atomic operations on user-defined types. How can I do something similar but for webgpu?

Does webgpu have any atomic operations on a 64-bit value?  Like compare-exchange?  Otherwise you'll need some kind of locking.  If there's only one writer it could be a seqlock where the readers can detect tearing and retry a read.  If modifications are infrequent, it can work well.

If all you can do is write separate u32 elements one at a time, you can't do an atomic RMW.  You're not even doing an atomic RMW on either element separately, just separate load and store, so even simplifying to a single u32 this algorithm isn't a thread-safe atomic increment.  Two threads could read the same initial value and both store the same final value, losing a count.  Or worse, a thread could load, get stuck or descheduled, and do its store much later, effectively overwriting many increments.

If you can do an atomic add on the low u32 and detect carry-out, which you can feed to an atomic RMW in the high half, it would then be possible to get the right final counter value once the dust settles.  Even though the two halves might be out of sync at any point while they're being modified.  Carry only propagates from low to high, and addition is commutative + associative.  So adding carry-outs from the low half into the high half can be done independently of the RMW on the low half.  (With a fetch_add, you can detect carry with sum = a+b / carry = sum < a, where a is the old val

@PeterCordes unfortunately, webgpu does not support u64 AT ALL yet. Even the type definition within the shader is not supported, let alone in atomics. I tried looking for a lock/barrier mechanism within the shader but with no results. I found atomic compare exchange for u32 however. I now understand how to increment the high half correctly (thank you for the great explanation!). but what about the low half and overflow? how do I prevent the buffer from overflowing?

Overflow (u32 wraparound) is the carry-out you detect with carry = sum < a.  Does u32 math in webgpu not work like C uint32_t where addition silently wraps?  In C, you literally do sum_low += input_low; sum_high += input_high + (sum_low < input_low).  (The compare can be against either input to the low add since it's commutative.  Doing an atomic RMW in terms of CAS means you already need both the old and new sum_low in variables, so can implement fetch_add or add_fetch.)

@PeterCordes it worked perfectly!! thank you so much!

Here is a solution for atomicAddU64, thanks to @PeterCordes!
Manually do the carry between a u32 low half and a u32 high half, with each u32 addition being an atomic RMW.  This requires the fetch_add / atomicAdd return value from the low half so we can check for carry-out.
Since we only have 2 halves, not a wider integer, we don't need to handle carry-in and carry-out from the same add.  Just the sum = a+b; carry_out = sum<b; trick.
The total count at the end will be correct, but there's no way to read a correct snapshot of the current count while other threads are adding.  Multiple threads might have added to the low half and still be waiting to add to the high half, for example.
(It might be better to have each thread add into per-thread local accumulators to sum once at the end, instead of having all threads access a single shared variable all the time.)
fn main() {
    // .....

    // convert the value from u32 or f32 to 2-buffer representation of u64
    let b: vec2u = tou64(value);

    // low: no need for modulu since it will wrap by itself
    // take old value on the buffer to check for carry
    let oldValue = atomicAdd(&buffer[low_index], b.y);
    // high: add high part + carry
    // check if the sum cause value to wrap
    atomicAdd(&buffer[high_index], b.x + u32((oldValue + b.y) < b.y));
}

To convert u64 to vec2u and back:
// this is just a pseudocode! wgsl doesn't support u64 yet
// do this operation in c++/js or while data processing
fn u64ToVec2u(value: u64) -> vec2u {
    let low = u32(value);
    let high = u32(value >> 32);
    return vec2u(high, low);
}

fn vec2uToU64(value: vec2u) -> u64 {
    return (value.x << 32) + value.y; // x = high, y = low
}


and here's a solution for float computations as well, can be done in wgsl
// to save 2 ^ 10 = 1024 (ie 3 digits after the decimal point)
const DEGREE_TO_SAVE = 10; 
fn tou64(value: f32) -> vec2u {
    // modulu is important here!! 
    // because converting from float to u32 will not automatically wrap
    let low = u32((value * pow(2., DEGREE_TO_SAVE)) % pow(2., 32));
    let high = u32(value /  pow(2., 32 - DEGREE_TO_SAVE));
    return vec2u(high, low);
}

fn tof32(value: vec2u) -> f32 {
    return f32(value.x) * pow(2., 32 - DEGREE_TO_SAVE) + f32(value.y) / pow(2., DEGREE_TO_SAVE);

}


Minor caveat.  Extending this code from 64 bits  to 96 bits has some slight trickiness. The above code can't distinguish between adding 0xFFFFFFFF with a carry of 1 and adding 0 with no carry.  When doing the third (and subsequent) additions, the test for outgoing carry is result <= addend if there was an incoming carry, and result < addend if there wasn't.
